# Unable to git pull while using putty

Tags: git, ssh

I have two machines (a. Ubuntu machine b. Windows machine)

I have cloned code from a github repo in the Ubuntu machine and I am able to run git commands if I login into the Ubuntu machine (directly)

But if I login into the Ubuntu machine (using the same userid) via a Windows machine (using putty), then it fails to pull code on a git pull. It results in a permission denied error

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Why I am not able to pull code if I login from my Windows machine?

Comment: Are you using the same user to login via SSH from windows , I mean same user you used to login directly in your ubuntu

Comment: yes, am using the same user credentials to login into the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is your $HOME defined properly once logged through your putty session? It will be needed for getting to your ssh public/private keys.

Comment: are you logging in via the GUI when directly logging in on the Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your ssh private key is being unlocked by the ssh-agent setup by your GUI login on the Ubuntu machine, whereas your putty/ssh connection isn't setting up an ssh-agent correctly to get access to your private key.

You could try running `eval $(ssh-agent)` and `ssh-add` to setup an agent on your ssh connection.

I'm surprised that `git` isn't asking for your password in this case though?